# lstinline has Invalid UTF-8 byte 167

Tags: listings, unicode

Possible duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24528/having-problems-with-listings-and-utf-8-can-it-be-fixed)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
  parskip=full,% empty line after each paragraph.
  twoside=false% not a 2-sided print for a book.
]{scrbook}

% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % For non-English languages
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % listings needs this encoding instead!

\usepackage{listings, tcolorbox}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins,theorems,xparse}
\NewTotalTCBox{\inlinebox}{ O{white} v}
{ tcbox raise base,
  arc=2pt,
  nobeforeafter,% makes the box inline
  colback=#1!10!white,% pales given color for background
  boxsep=0pt,left=1pt,right=1pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,
  boxrule=0pt}
{\lstinline[style=tcblatex,texcsstyle=*\color{blue}\bfseries]§#2§}
\newcommand\cil{\inlinebox[green]}

\begin{document}

\cil|\TeX| (\TeX) is a control word because it is made up of letters. Any non-letter will end the sequence.

\end{document}
```

This all works if I do `\UseRawInputEncoding`, as per [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429190/package-inputenc-error-invalid-utf-8-byte-147).

Should I do that? Or is there something more correct that I should do?

`\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` also works, by the way.

Comment: How can it work? That's not a complete document anybody could compile, but just a fragment. Please complete it.

Comment: No. You should declare the input encoding you're using, as David's answer says.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problematic part is:

```
\lstinline[...]§#2§
```

The character `§` is *not* an ASCII character.

### 8-bit TeX engines (TeX, pdfTeX)

Since package `listings` does *not* support multi-byte encodings, the text encoding is limited to an 8-bit encoding as `latin1`. This encoding should then
be declared by

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

For greater portability, I recommend to use a different fence character from the ASCII range (`|`, `&`, ...). This avoids problems, when the input file encoding is changed to UTF-8.

### Unicode engines (LuaTeX, XeTeX)

Here, the character `§` is just *one* character (big char) and it can be used as fence character for `\lstinline` of package `listings`.

However, the best supported input encoding for LuaTeX or XeTeX is UTF-8. Therefore, the input file should be re-encoded from Latin-1 to UTF-8.

Comment: Which UTF-8 fence character do you recommend? Should I use the `minted` package instead if I need UTF-8 support?

Comment: @JonWong It depends on the characters used inside the verbatim text. If `|` is free, then it looks nice in the source code.