# Exporting doxygen to pdf using Latex - Package inputenc Error

Tags: input-encodings, doxygen

I'm trying to generate a single pdf file out of doxygen documentation.

I run doxygen and then in `latex` folder I run the make file. The making process runs for a moment and then halts with this message:

```
[23]

! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "93.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.194 \end{DoxyParams}


?
```

I checked similare questions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429190/package-inputenc-error-invalid-utf-8-byte-147) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/inputenc-error-unicode-char-u8-error-while-trying-to-write-a-degree-symbol) but they didn't solve my problem.

I tried adding `\UseRawInputEncoding` at the beginning of `refman.tex` file, I tried to use `utf8x` instead of `utf8` but this didn't solve my problem.

Any suggestions how to fix this problem?

**UPDATE**

I'm using `Doxygen 1.8.16` and working on `Windows 7` (64 bit machine). For latex I'm using `MikTex 2.9.7219`

I think this question belongs here because the problem is produced when trying to "compile" the latex source file.

Regarding the MWE, I think it is difficult to include it here because this file is autotically generated by doxygen and it has over 200 lines, therefore I'm not sure how to make a minimal working example out of it.

**UPDATE II**

Well, I'm not sure if this is what @albert means. But following is the `Makefile` used by Doxygen to export a pdf file out of latex file.

```
LATEX_CMD=pdflatex

all: refman.pdf

pdf: refman.pdf

refman.pdf: clean refman.tex
    $(LATEX_CMD) refman
    makeindex refman.idx
    $(LATEX_CMD) refman
    latex_count=8 ; \
    while egrep -s 'Rerun (LaTeX|to get cross-references right)' refman.log && [ $$latex_count -gt 0 ] ;\
        do \
          echo "Rerunning latex...." ;\
          $(LATEX_CMD) refman ;\
          latex_count=`expr $$latex_count - 1` ;\
        done
    makeindex refman.idx
    $(LATEX_CMD) refman


clean:
    rm -f *.ps *.dvi *.aux *.toc *.idx *.ind *.ilg *.log *.out *.brf *.blg *.bbl refman.pdf
```

Comment: Looks like that doxygen is creating some non understood code. Which doxygen version are you using (to be on the save side which text version and on which OS)? Please Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see the original doxygen input as well as the differences between the default doxygen configuration file and the used one. NOTE I'm not sure whether the question is best here or at  https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Don't include the LaTeX code but the small file used by doxygen that triggers the problem as at that moment we (I) can check what is wrong and be able to suggest a solution.

Comment: @alber, if you mean the `Makefile`, I've included it in my question. Is this what you mean?

Comment: No I mean the source code (ifile with extension like .h or .c that is used by doxygen to generated the code from), the Makefile is also generated by doxygen so this is generated as well.

Comment: your generated file has byte hex 93 in it which is not a valid UTF-8 byte, so the file will not be understood by any application expecting a Unicode text file, Usually in these cases the text is really in latin 1 not UTF-8 so you can simply declare it as such to latex, but in iso-8859-1 byte hex 93 is the control character SET TRANSMIT STATE so it seems unlikely that that was intended?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that is the explanation from the LaTeX side, but the real problem is why is the character in the code of OP, I have the feeling that it has to do something with his local setting (keyboard used). To give an answer we have to know what character OP used so it can either be handled by OP (getting another character, well know problem are e,g, with hypens / minus signs on German Keyboards) or on the doxygen side so doxygen can generate code that is automatically understood (this is probably not realizable for all situations but we now don't really know the cause of the problem).

Comment: I use a german keyboard. What do you mean with 'OP'? I tried something weird and it worked. I copied the error message from the terminal and un-intentionally I pasted it back to the terminal (as the terminal was waiting for some input from my side). Afterwards, the exporting process continued and completed and a pdf was generated. Does this tell anything about the problem and the solution?

Comment: Show the latex file, if needed upload it somewhere. Then one can at least identify where the broken utf8 has been created.