# Inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "FC

Tags: unicode, font-encodings, newunicodechar

When compiling my code in Texmaker I get this error:

> Error Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "FC.

I don't know why. Can somebody help me?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,titlepage]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{esvect} % Für Vektoren
\sisetup{exponent-product = \cdot, output-product = \cdot, per-mode = fraction}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\quelle}{%
  \footnotesize Quelle:
}
\usepackage{microtype}% verbesserter Randausgleich
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage[ super , square , sort&compress ] {natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtdin}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{MeineBib.bib}
 
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Article{Wikipedia2021,
  author  = {Wikipedia},
  journal = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gleichwer ... note-D10-1},
  title   = {Gleichrichtwert},
  year    = {2021},
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:bibtex;}

Der Gleichrichtwert wird wie folgt definiert: \cite{Wikipedia2021}
\end{filecontents}




\addsec{1) Zitieren}% 

Dieser in der Elektrotechnik verwendete Begriff steht für den Mittelwert 
des Betrages dieser Größe \cite{Wikipedia2021}

\bibliography{MeineBib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Have you seen this thread? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429190/package-inputenc-error-invalid-utf-8-byte-147

Comment: Did you really run this exact example in a new, empty folder? It compiles without the error for me. (Note that `filecontents` as used will not overwrite existing files, so if your `MeineBib` contains different content than shown here that could explain it.) You may also want to delete the `.aux` and `.bbl` files and recompile. In any case errors like this are usually caused by wrong/not matching file encodings. With a modern LaTeX (April 2018 or newer) you should look into encoding all your files as UTF-8. (Your `.bib` file claims to be UTF-8, so that would be good.)

Comment: There was a very similar question on goLaTeX recently with a screenshot of an error message (https://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?p=115251#p115251) complaining about `"FC` and `"F6`: That are the positions of `ü` and `ö` in Latin-1 (ISO 8859-1). That would strongly suggest one of the files is not actually saved as UTF-8, but as Latin-1. You have to find out which file that is and you have to make sure your editor (or whichever program writes it), uses UTF-8 from now on.

Comment: Your write-up is not easy to follow. For instance, you mention that loading the `inputenc` package throws an error; however, your same colde does *not* load the `inputenc` package, making it pretty much impossible to follow what may be going on. Also, what is the sentence "Der Gleichrichtwert wird wie folgt definiert: \cite{Wikipedia2021}" doing inside the bib file? Please clarify. For instance, do please inform us whether your real document loads the `inputenc` package and, if so, with which option, or options, it gets loaded.

Comment: @Mico Though to be fair modern LaTeX basically pre-loads `inputenc`, so you can get `inputenc` errors without an explicit `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. That seems to be what is happening here: No `inputenc` is loaded, so modern LaTeX assumes UTF-8, but the document is probably in something like Latin-1.

Comment: @JasminNiederbacher On close inspection I'm pretty confident that there is nothing wrong with your `.bib` file. The problem is that your `.tex` file is not encoded as UTF-8, but instead as something else (quite probably Latin-1 [ISO 8859-1]). You have two options: (1) Convert your `.tex` file to UTF-8 or (2) tell LaTeX to assume Latin-1 encoding (and then recode the `.bib` file). Since UTF-8 is the de facto standard file encoding nowadays I strongly recommend option (1). ...

Comment: ... Make a backup of your current files! Then set UTF-8 as standard encoding in TeXmaker (and all your other editors, https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/software/texmaker_v5.0.2/share/texmaker/usermanual_en.html#SECTION01) It may be possible that TeXmaker does not change the encoding of existing files automatically to avoid messing up your document. Try to convince TeXmaker to recode it to UTF-8. If that does not work, you can try Notepad++, which is very good at those sorts of things

Comment: If you really must work with files in older encodings, the `selinput` package was created for this. It detects the file encoding automatically, so it will still work properly even if re-encoded. I also recommend using UTF-8. (In NFC form, as required by PDFTeX.)